# Duplicate field names not yeilding results in Rest API Call from Salesforce to Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, api, wsdl, salesforce-to-salesforce

We are trying to view One Salesforce instance results in another Salesforce.
We have an API Call Which Works.

But when we do a Query like: Select Name, Owner.Name from Account

We get the account name or the Owner Name. We are unable to get both of then.

API Code:

```
    public String OwnerName;   
    private String[] OwnerName_type_info = new String[]{'Name','urn:Owner.partner.soap.sforce.com','String','1','1','true'};
    public Sobject Owner;   
    private String[] Owner_type_info = new String[]{'Owner','urn:partner.soap.sforce.com','sobject','1','1','true'};
    public String Name;
    private String[] Name_type_info = new String[]{'Name','urn:Account.partner.soap.sforce.com','String','1','1','true'};
```

}

Call:

```
  string us='User';
  string ps='Pass';

  partnerSoapSforceCom.soap conn1= new partnerSoapSforceCom.soap();
  conn1.SessionHeader = new partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element ();
  partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = new              partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult();
  partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginScopeHeader_element ls1=new  partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginScopeHeader_element();
  conn1.LoginScopeHeader=ls1;
  loginResult =conn1.login(us,ps);
  conn1.endpoint_x =loginResult.ServerUrl;

  conn1.Sessionheader.sessionid = loginResult.sessionid;
  partnerSoapSforceCom.queryResult qr1 = new partnerSoapSforceCom.queryResult();

     String strQuery = 'Select Name, Owner.Name from Account acc where Id like \'xxxxxxxxxx\'';  
     qr1=conn1.query(strQuery);
     wrapAccountList=new List<WrapperAccount>();
     wrapAccountList.clear();

     for (sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x obj : qr1.records)
        {

             wrpAcc=new WrapperAccount();

             wrpAcc.OwnerName = obj.OwnerName;
             wrpAcc.Name=obj.Name;

             wrapAccountList.add(wrpAcc);

        }
```

Comment: the title of your post ought to change to SOAP API instead of REST API

Answer (score 2):

You will need to work with the `sObject_x` fields to get the results.

However, Usually Wsdl2Apex doesn't support the `any` element return type in sObject. It is this field that usually contains the actual field values from the SOQL query beyond the record Id and type.

E.g. Here is a version of sObject that was created by another tool and handles the `<xsd:any>` element by converting to a List of DOM.XmlNode. However, to get this to work it needs to make the HTTP Requests and process the responses outside of `WebServiceCallout.invoke`.

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
// Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement

public class sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom {

    // Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement

    public class sObject_x {
        public String type_x;
        public String[] fieldsToNull;
        public String Id;
        public List<DOM.XmlNode> anyElement;
        private String[] type_x_type_info = new String[]{'type','urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com','string','1','1','false'};
        private String[] fieldsToNull_type_info = new String[]{'fieldsToNull','urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com','string','0','-1','true'};
        private String[] Id_type_info = new String[]{'Id','urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com','ID','1','1','true'};
        private String[] anyElement_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement','urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com','List<DOM.XmlNode>','0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'type_x','fieldsToNull','Id','anyElement'};
    }
```

How did you generate the Apex classes from the WSDL for your example? If it was with the build in WSDL2Apex I'm kind of surprised it even compiles as sObject doesn't have elements for `name` or `OwnerName`. You would need to convert the polymorphic result to an Account object, which the Partner API doesn't provide.